# Getting a USER_CANCELLED token error while trying to authenticate using Apple MusicKit SDK

Tags: android, apple-musickit

I'm trying to interface the Apple Musickit SDK to my android app. I was able to get the authentication working initially. But I'm getting a USER_CANCELLED token error on my phone/device every time I try to connect. I'm getting the same error now while trying to authenticate on the example sdk_test app(even though it was working earlier) that is shipped with the SDK, What's fishy is that the code runs fine on other phones except mine now(using the same dev token too). Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Any updates on this? Also found a lot of other people with the same problem on this forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/411149#411149

Answer (score -1):

This was a bug, and has been fixed in latest apple music app relese.

Updating apple music to the latest release solves this issue.